# Does "Dispose" dispose of every instance of a class set to the same object?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, dispose

Since `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` implement `IDisposable`, I'm wrapping them in `using` statements.

However, I'm creating them in methods and then passing them to the `using` statements, and therefore wanted to know whether the closing brace of the `using` will dispose of the `SqlCommand` created by the method.

So I tried this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandTimeout = 10;
    command.Disposed += s_Disposed;    
    using (SqlCommand tempCommand = command) { }//This is where even "command" is supposed to get disposed.
    Text = command.CommandTimeout.ToString();
}

void s_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Disposed");
}
```

And was surprised to see that the `MessageBox` did show implying that it was disposed, but the Text was "10".

Why?

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. "every instance of a class set to the same object" doesn't mean anything. Every instance is the same as itself, and so is every object. You are confusing class instances (objects) with the references to them. You should edit your question to remove this obscurity.

Comment: @EJP OK. So what are `command` and `tempCommand` called if not "instances"?

Comment: @ispiro - Variables. They hold a reference to an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, objects which implement `IDisposable` (e.g. an `SqlConnection`) do so because something, somewhere in the universe (like an SQL server), has been asked to do something on their behalf (e.g. open and maintain a connection) and will keep doing so until instructed otherwise.  Generally, the `IDisposable` object will need to have those outside things act on its behalf if it is to honor requests that it expects to receive (e.g. perform an SQL operation).  The purpose of `Dispose` is not to actually destroy the object upon which it is called, but rather to let the object know that since nobody else will be needing it, it should in turn let any outside entities that are doing anything on its behalf know that they no longer need to do so (e.g. since nobody will be asking the `SqlConnection` to perform any more requests, it no longer needs to have a server keep a connection open for it).

If, after `Dispose` has been called on an object, it is asked to do something which would require the assistance of the outside entity which is no longer available, it is better for the object to throw `ObjectDisposedException` itself *than for the action to fail in some other way*.  On the other hand, if an object is asked to do something which can be done perfectly well without use of the outside entity, it is often appropriate for it do so.  Code which makes use of an `IDisposable` object should generally refrain from using any members after `Dispose` which are not explicitly documented as remaining usable, and should avoid assuming that a member which remains useful after `Dispose` on one version of a class will always do so.  Nonetheless, it is in many cases nicer for a class to specify that particular members may be used after `Dispose` than to go through the effort of ensuring that they cannot be.

Answer (score 1):

It does dispose the `SqlCommand` instance properly and it does not matter how much references you have to it. They all point to the same instance anyway.

However, `CommandTimeout` does not raise an exception even on a disposed object.

Comment: But if it's disposed – how does it still remember the "10"? (It's _not_ the default.)

Comment: `Dispose` is for freeing unmanaged resources. In this case the connection to the SQL Server and possibly anything else that is not really governed by the CLR. `CommandTimeout` however is most likely just a normal property that is used when making a query but otherwise is just an `int` field in the `SqlCommand` class. So it is *not* part of the *unmanaged* resources but rather something the garbage collector can clean up quite easily by himself. Not to mention that `Dispose` would have no way to clean up a single `int` anyway.

Comment: @ispiro - disposed just means the `Dispose` method has been called, not that the whole object is eliminated.